# Serilog Sink ddls are not copied when reference only in appsettings

Tags: serilog

I am using serilog with the sinks File and RollingFile in a crosscutting dll that delivers a logging service. I am configuring with the Appsettings nuget, therefore I have no static dependency to the mentioned sinks. However I do need them at runtime and they are not copied to the bin folder of the application, only to the bin folder of the dll. That means I get a Runtime Exception because the sink-dlls are not there. Is there a way to fix that? My workaround is creating a Variable of type RollingFileSink that I never use. But it is kind of ugly. UPDATE: that solution does not work in Release btw.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before with Serilog, and the way I resolved it was to create a static reference to a type inside the assemblies I needed, via an assembly-level attribute that I declare inside the `AssemblyInfo.cs` of my main project.

Something like this:

```
[assembly: ImplicitDependency(typeof(Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile.RollingFileSink))]
[assembly: ImplicitDependency(typeof(Serilog.Sinks.File.PeriodicFlushToDiskSink))]
// etc...
```

---

And this is the attribute I created inside my project...

```
/// <summary>
/// Indicates that the marked assembly depends on the type that is specified in the constructor.
/// Typically used to force a compile-time dependency to the assembly that contains the type.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class ImplicitDependencyAttribute : Attribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ImplicitDependencyAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dependencyType">A type from the assembly that is used dynamically.</param>
    public ImplicitDependencyAttribute(Type dependencyType)
    {
        DependencyType = dependencyType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the dependent type reference.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The dependent type reference.</value>
    public Type DependencyType { get; private set; }
}
```